# Is this a feasible way to straight-couple to a gear?

Tags: motors, gears, car, coupling

I have some car window motors that I would like to directly couple to some roller-type shades in my house.  I would like to introduce a direct coupling mechanism rather than use some sort of chain.

In a car these motors are used in a rack-and-pinion configuration, with the pinion gear on the motor and the rack gear on a scissor mechanism:
[image]

Here are some photos of the motor and the gear.  I have not been successful in removing the gear without opening and damaging the worm-gear enclosure (a greasy mess):
[image]

My proposal is to make a coupler out of steel or brass dowel pins:
[image]

Does this seem like it would work?  Do people use couplers like this?  I have a small Taig lathe and a little CNC that I can use to place the dowel pin holes and make the coupler.

Comment: your idea is doable ... a 6 point wrench socket might be a simpler solution

Comment: your questions seek opinions ... that is off topic here

Comment: get a few more window motors and get the gears of them to do a 1:1 drive.

Comment: I'm not seeing the 6-point wrench solution.  Seems this would require a coupler with 7 sides?